# How to specify node version in CircleCI Cypress Orb

Tags: cypress, circleci

When I try to use the Cypress Orb in CircleCI, I get an error which says I'm using the wrong node version.

I've tried multiple different configs with and without the Orb and have had no success.

Here's my very basic `config.yml` file copied directly from the docs

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1
workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run:
          yarn: true
```

This is the error displayed by CircleCI

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
yarn install --frozen-lockfile
yarn install v1.10.1
[1/5] Validating package.json...
error app@1.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^10.15.1". Got "10.13.0"
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Exited with code 1
```

I suspect I have to use nvm to specify the correct node version, but I haven't been able to figure out how or where.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1
workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run:
          executor: cypress/base-10
          yarn: true
```